# How to reference environmental variables inside an upstart installed launch file?

Tags: ros, robot-upstart, environment-variables

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have successfully managed to install a launch file but upon rebooting found that none of the environmental variables referenced in the launch file are found. Granted, the launch files are guilty of liberal usage of $(optenv VARIABLE default) and as such many things are taking the default value. This now makes sense because, as I understand it, services run with most of the environmental variables stripped away.  However I'd really like to avoid simply hard code the information into the launch files because the robot's hardware configuration is saved in these variables and this one launch file has to be installed on several different types of units.

I saw that for normal linux services the work around is to source an additional file inside the service file but I even find where robot_upstart installs the newly created service, which I confusingly called *ros* as well.  I didn't see it /etc/default or /etc/init.d . My best guess was to source the ".robotrc" in the *devel/setup.bash* and include it with **--setup** option?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/205905/how-to-reference-environmental-variables-inside-an-upstart-installed-launch-file?/) by [brendan](https://answers.ros.org/users/21977/brendan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2015-03-25

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Apologies if I take your intent wrong, but defining environmental variables upon `upstart` is discussed in [clearpathrobotics/robot_upstart#44](https://github.com/clearpathrobotics/robot_upstart/pull/44) (and not formally documented anywhere AFAICT). So as far as you successfully define env vars that way, you should be able to reference to them in your launch files in the way you mentioned.

CC @mikepurvis

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2017-12-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0